# Serverless get list of all existing endpoints from Api handler

Tags: endpoint, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I am trying to create a service root endpoint which will respond with a list of all existing path templates. I can create the response manually. Is there any way to get the list other than this manual approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using serverless with aws + API Gateway you probably can use get resources method from the API Gatway methods from the aws sdk

example in JS sdk:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html#getResources-property